# Scala and MySQL JDBC Driver

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, slick

I'm currently working on a SBT-based Scala project and I need to use MySQL as database (through Slick 3.0.0 library).

The issue is that I can't connect to the database because of this exception:

```
> service[ERROR] java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
service[ERROR]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
service[ERROR]  at slick.jdbc.DriverBasedJdbcDataSource$class.registerDriver(JdbcDataSource.scala:60)
service[ERROR]  at slick.jdbc.DriverJdbcDataSource.registerDriver(JdbcDataSource.scala:72)
service[ERROR]  at slick.jdbc.DriverJdbcDataSource.<init>(JdbcDataSource.scala:78)
service[ERROR]  at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$class.forURL(JdbcBackend.scala:101)
service[ERROR]  at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$$anon$3.forURL(JdbcBackend.scala:33)
```

[image]

What I've done so far (see screenshot):

- I made sure the MySQL server is running.
- I've added **mysql-connector-java** dependency the **build.sbt** file.
  The jar gets downloaded correctly (see column on the left).
- I've used this to get a connection to the database:

  ```
  val db = Database.forURL(
    "jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/service",
    "service",
    "service",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  )
  ```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: if I run "sbt console" in the directory, `classForName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` works

Comment: if you put, above the line you've shown, `val driverClass = classForName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`, since that works in the console? alternatively, however you are starting up your JVM, `-Djdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: The following, `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`, worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/service` not `jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/service`. You are missing a slash and colon after mysql.

Tried on my own project. The error with the wrong jdbc URL gives me same exception as yours. I guess this exception is misleading.

Comment: The `DriverManager` queries each registered `Driver` in turn if it will connect using the URL, if none accept it (eg because it has the wrong prefix as in this case), then "No suitable driver" has been found. I am not sure how that would be misleading; it is a result of the service provider architecture of `DriverManager`.