# MySql with Slick 3.0 giving "No suitable driver"

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm trying to get Slick 3.0 running with MySql. I've made the following changes to the hello-slick-3.0 activator project:

1. In `application.conf` I've removed the `h2mem1` entry and replaced it with:

   `horridDBStuff = {
     url = "utterlyhorriddb.blahblahblah.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"
     driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     connectionPool = disabled
     keepAliveConnection = true
   }`
2. I've replaced each `Database.forConfig("h2mem1")` entry in the scala
   code with `Database.forConfig("horridDBStuff")`
3. I've replaced each `import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._` with 
   `import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`
4. In `build.sbt` I've added to `libraryDependencies` the item 
   `"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"`

It compiles fine, but running gives the error `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` coming from the line `val db = Database.forConfig("horridDBStuff")`.

How can I get Slick 3.0 running with MySql? Am I missing something simple here, or are there any other working examples? Thanks.

Comment: Answered this some days back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164015/scala-and-mysql-jdbc-driver/30164614 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The URL in `application.conf` was in the wrong format. Should be

`url = "jdbc:mysql://utterlyhorriddb.blahblah.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/aardvark_schema"`

where you've already created `ardvark_schema` in your database.

(That fixes the db access issue that I was asking about, but you'll still get a key-spec error. To fix that you need to remove the `O.PrimaryKey` entry from `Tables.scala` for `"COF_NAME"`, which is described here: [How to get around Slick 3.0 schema creation getting errors due to key specs without length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573125/how-to-get-around-slick-3-0-schema-creation-getting-errors-due-to-key-specs-with).)